# How to run application that is located on file system but not installed?

Tags: 11.04, command-line

Recently my friend 'installed' testdisk for me on my laptop and used it to show me some stuff with it. But now I would like to launch it again and I do not know how to do it. I have tried to go Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then go to Testdisk's directory and try 'sudo testdisk' but there is no such a command in the system. I have Testdisk in /home/monkey(my user name)/testdisk-6.12

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nautilus filemanager, when you right click **testdisk_static** select **Properties**. In the Property dialogue, that comes up go to the tab **Permissions** there check the box that says **Allow executing file as program**. Once you have done that, you can double click on **testdisk_static** in nautilus and tell it to run the program if testdisk as a graphical user interface.

[image: executing binaries]

If it has no GUI, you will have to run it in shell. You can do the following:

```
cd PathToTestDisk         # go to direcotry testdisk is located
chmod +x testdisk_static  # allow for the binaries to be executed
./testdisk_static         # execute program
```

Edit your question with the exact problem if that doesn't work.

If you want testdisk to show up as a regular shell command you can create a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin` like this:

```
ln -s /Path/To/Test/Disk/testdisk_static /usr/local/bin/testdisk
```

In order for this to work, you must use **absolute paths** on the first argument.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's perfectly what I was looking for :)